# How do I associate multiple values to one dictionary key?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a key `Soldier`. I have many keys like this, I'm trying to make a dictionary that contains all of the units in a particular video game and associates with those units their various stats, including HP, attack, speed, and so on.

So for example, I want to associate these values to `Soldier`:
'115', '4.2', '8', '0', '0', '.35', '.15', '.99'

Is it possible to associate all of these values to one key within a dictionary? If not, should I make multiple dictionaries, one for each stat (ex. HP)?

Comment: `{"soldier": [ 1,2,3,4,5,]}` ? why not create a soldier class that holds the correct things and keep them in a list?

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding what you are trying to do correctly,

Each soldier should be a list of dict instead

```
[{"soldierId":001,"HP":100,"Agility":4.2},{"soldierId":002,"HP":80,"Agility":7.2}]
```

It would be alot better to do OOP and create a class for soldiers with each of the stats as an attribute

[update]

You could make use of inheritance.

E.g. Army --> Unit --> Soldier.

E.g. Army --> Artillery --> Catapult

So an army class consist of multiple units and within each unit there are many soldiers. You could create a unitId and soldierId to identify each unit and soldier in the army

The above is just a sample and you could further classify them according to your needs.

E.g. Army --> Unit --> Commanding Officer

E.g. Army --> Unit --> Captain

E.g. Army --> Unit --> Soldier etc.

or even

E.g. Army --> Unit --> FootSoldier --> Commanding Officer

E.g. Army --> Unit --> FootSoldier --> Captain

E.g. Army --> Unit --> FootSoldier --> Soldier

E.g. Army --> Unit --> Machinery --> Catapult etc.

Your design will depends on your program's functional need.

Comment: So could I do something like making a "Unit" class and then just have a "Name" attribute, as well as attributes for each stat? In the future I want to be able to search for a name like "Footsoldier" or "Catapult" and then pull the relevant stats like its HP.